# global keyword outside the function in php

Tags: php

As we know, global keyword makes variable( or object, array) visible inside current function we are dealing with

```
<?php

$some_var = 'some string';

function __test(){
    global $some_var;
    echo $some_var; // some string
}
```

But some dev's still use the global keyword outside the functions
at first look it doesn't make any sense to me.

Well, the question is: Does it make any sense to use 'global' keyword outside the function ???

Comment: Are you sure of the scope that it is being used?

Comment: I saw even in index.php file, "global $some_var" - really it won't ever be inside any function. I'm sure about the scope

Comment: @metal_fan I suspect you saw the guts of a function in a separate file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php):

> Using global keyword outside a function is not an error. It can be used if the file is included from inside a function.

Essentially you could have your function guts in a different file than your function declaration. These guts would then be included into the function. This would give the impression, if you view the guts alone, of a user using `global` outside of a function, however the fact is that when this code is interpreted, it will be interpreted from *within* a function.

```
$name = "Jonathan";

function doSomething () {
  include 'functionGuts.php';
}
```

Where the contents of our `functionGuts.php` file could be:

```
global $name;
echo "Hello, " . $name;
```

When viewed on its own, `functionGuts.php` will give the impression that `global` is being used outside of a function, when in reality it's being used like this:

```
$name = "Jonathan";

function doSomething () {
  global $name;
  echo "Hello, " . $name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Global keyword outside of functions does not do anything at all. but that file might be included within a function.

Another thing i use it not is to make my codes readable and more structured. any variable that i want to bo accessed using global keyword in a function, i declare it using global in the main file, so just a quick glance and i know that it is referenced somewhere as a global. (meaning don't rename anyhow as other is used somewhere else... :) )