# Declaring and using global variables does not behave same in core php as in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, global-variables, global

In Core php for global scope **Example-1** works ok, and prints `B=15` because of addition of `b=a+b`

but in **codeigniter it prints `B=10` which is `$b`'s initial value**, this means global scope does not work same as core php in codeigniter.

**Example-1 works ok in core php but does not work in codeigniter**

```
$a = 5;
$b = 10;

function myTest() {
    global $a, $b;
    $b = $a + $b;
}

myTest();
echo "B=$b"; //prints "B=15" in core php and "B=10" in Codeigniter
```

**Example-2 works ok in core php and in codeigniter Both**

```
global $a,$b;
$a = 5;
$b = 10;

function myTest() {
    global $a, $b;
    $b = $a + $b;
}

myTest();
echo "B=$b";//prints "B=15" in core php and in Codeigniter both.
```

i have used this **Example-2** in my codeigniter view.

I know that the **Example-2** is not correct syntactically but **Example-1** is correct syntactically but then my question is :

why it is not working in codeigniter and why **Example-2** which has two time initialization of `global` works in codeigniter

Comment: Where do you have the above code? In a function/method? Please show us _all_ the relevant code so we get the context/scope (it matters).

Comment: _"i have used this Example-2 in my codeigniter view."_ - Are you defining functions in your views?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, yes because it is small functionality, and it does not make any difference if i define it in controller, it behaves same as i have told here.

Comment: The view (where you write your code) is most likely being executed inside a class (which means that you're not in the global scope). Then, if you use `global $a;` in your function, it will use `$a` from the global scope, while you've defined `$a` in the views scope (which is most likely a class method). But, when you use `global $a;` before you define the variable (in your second example), you will be using the `$a`-variable from the global scope on both occasions, which is why that works.

Comment: As @MagnusEriksson points out - it may be as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308021/global-keyword-outside-the-function-in-php

Comment: Here's some in-depth explanations about variable scopes in PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: I would also recommend that you define view functions outside of the views. Have as little logic as possible in the actual views (aim at having nothing than presentation logic). That will make it much easier to reuse both views and view functions.

Comment: Thanks @MagnusEriksson, i think i have misunderstood, actually codeigniter view is called from class so it is not in global scope, i have messed it up little bit, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: So @MagnusEriksson, do i have to delete my question or better it will be if you can put your comment as answer so i can accept it as my answer.

Comment: @HaritsinhGohil - I've added an answer.

Comment: @HaritsinhGohil use a `MY_Controller` for "global vars" in CI

Comment: @Alex, i know that but i want to use global variables using `global` keyword, as we do in core php so.

Comment: idk why you would want that when there is better way of doing things. there is a reason why nobody uses `global` vars anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view (where you write your code) is being included and executed inside a class method (which means that the code in your views aren't in the global scope).

#### For example #1:

If you use `global $a;` in your function (which technically will be defined inside the method), it will use `$a` from the global scope, while you've defined `$a` in the views scope (which is the scope of the view-class method).

#### For example #2:

When you use `global $a;` before you define the variable, you will be using the `$a`-variable from the global scope on both occasions, which is why that works

#### References:

You can read more about [variable scopes in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

#### Notes:

1. This isn't anything specific to CodeIgniter. This is simply how scopes work in PHP.
2. Using `global` is considered an anti-pattern and should be avoided when ever possible (which you can, in most situations) since it can make debugging a real pain and you can easily introduce unwanted side effects.
3. I would recommend that you don't put functions inside the views. Add them as helper functions that you can load before you load your views. That will make it easier to find your functions (since they are all in the same place) and can easily be reused.